# AngularJS : unable to show parameter with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get an input from user and pass it to second page named `other`

added a new parameter in state definition called `test`

You can check the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CIwC5Vx9UXUa7jXiC5BP?p=preview)

the `other` looks like this

```
<li><a ui-sref="other">#/other/fooVal</a></li>
```

If i try to change it like belowe it just get disabled

```
<li><a ui-sref="other{{test: 'test1'">#/other/fooVal</a></li>
```

**What should id do to show user input in `other` page**

PS: the other sref works fine

Answer (score 1):

`<a ui-sref="other{{test: 'test1'">#/other/fooVal</a>`

should be

`<a ui-sref="other({test: 'test1'})">#/other/fooVal</a>`

Note how it's an object in parenthesis `({ })`, *not* an expression block `{{ }}`.

Comment: it disables it again.you wrote the syntax right but it's not for here.you can check it.

Comment: @Mojtaba What do you mean by "it's not for here"? I tested it on your example, it works fine.

Comment: thank you.it solved part of the problem but i'm still unable to show the typed message in the 'other' page.

Comment: I think the issue there is that you have different scopes that aren't available to each other.